# NULL in double array C++ (with an example)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
double calculateAverage(double *a);

int main(){

    double *dArray;
    int n, m;

    cout<<"\nplease enter the size of the array: ";
    cin>>n;
    dArray = new double[n];

    for(m=0; m<n; m++){
        cout<<"\nplease enter the number: ";
        cin>>dArray[m];
    }
    *(dArray+m+1) = NULL; // i add this, so for the address after m+1 to be NULL

    cout<<"\n the average of the array is : "<<calculateAverage(dArray)<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


double calculateAverage(double *a){
    double total = 0;
    int iCounter = 0;
    while(*a!=NULL){   // here is the problem!! why it can't be NULL or 0 or empty? // edit from a to *a
        total = total+*a;
        a++;
        iCounter++;
    }

    return total/(iCounter-1); //here edit, from iCounter to iCounter-1
}
```

i wonder why the pointer does not point to NULL ? can anyone enlighten me where the code went wrong?

thank you.

a typo, it should be "n" not "nn" in array assigning loop block.

Comment: Undefined behaviour doesn't have to work the way you want it to.

Comment: Have you heard of indentation?

Comment: cout<<"\nplease enter the size of the array: ";
    cin>>n;
    dArray = new double[n];

Comment: Are you getting mixed up between ASCII NUL and pointer NULL?  Your loop probably won't find NULL.

Comment: in the while loop condition even i change  *a!=NULL, it does not work.

Comment: @cyberion thats because arrays are not terminated with NULL (or anything else) unless you do that yourself. Since your code never placed a NULL there, if you were to find one it would only be sheer luck. EDIT: the previous statement assumes you meant the loop to be `while (*a != NULL)`... if you meant without the dereference, you will eventually terminate the loop, either by crashing due to invalid memory access, or when you overflow the address held by `a` -- neither of which are intended by you.

Comment: You missed a significant point: problem: `*(dArray + ...)` is not a pointer. It is a `doublw`. `NULL` is just another name for `0`, so you are not setting anything to `nullptr`. You are setting (and comparing against) zero. What if one of the values in the array is also zero?

Comment: @RaymondChen good point! thank you. i shall rethink of this implementation. dArray+... the pointer never points to NULL? unless make it point to a NULL?

Comment: let's say. i do something like double dArray[10]={1.1, 1.323, 2.3221,3.0908}. i only allocated 4 elements of the 10-element array. so what's the content of dArray[4],dArray[5],dArray[6]...? it should be NULL or what? since i did not initialise it, shouldn't it be empty (NULL)?

Answer (score 2):

You have no guarantees about a `NULL` terminator at the end of an array, in fact there is no such thing in C++ unless you use a specific sentinel by yourself (and under certain circumstances with `char*`). In addition, in your specific case, what you are doing makes no sense.

Pointers are addresses, what you are doing is just increase the address, how should it become `NULL`? From a practical point of view suppose that you pass address `a == 0x12345678` to the function, when you do `++a` you just increase it by `sizeof(double)`, this won't become zero (unless when overflowing maybe).

Since it's C++ just forget arrays and use a `std::vector` (or if you really want to use standard arrays pass the length as a parameter to the `calculateAverage` function).

Comment: in the while loop, how about *(a)!=NULL, can an address contain NULL value.

Comment: i just want to pass the array to the function, i do not want to pass the size of the array as parameter to the function. thank you for your explanation.

Comment: You array is not an array of pointers (eg. `double**`) so comparing a double to `NULL` makes no sense. You could do `*(a) != NULL` by using a `double**` but you will have to ensure that the sentinel is places.

Comment: Then use a `std::vector` or use a trick, like placing a `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` at the end of the array, so that you can use `std::isnan()` as your end condition.

Comment: *(dArray+m+1) = NULL; after for the loop assigns the value of the array. i force it to be a NULL, can i? it seems to work....

Answer (score 0):

The pointer is initialized with the address of the first element of the array allocated with new.  Incrementing the pointer moves it to the address of the next double in the array.  NULL is the adress at the beginning of memory, so your pointer won't be equal to it until it's iterated through the entire memory and wrapped around.

You need to modify your code so the iteration is based on the number of elements processed instead of the address the pointer is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see it you have a lot of mistakes

1. `*(dArray+m+1) = NULL` --> if you ment to put the 0 in the end of the array you should have used `*(dArray+m) = NULL`
2. you allocated an array of `n` doubles and you write the `null` to `n+1` (allocate `n+1` if you intend to use `n+1`...)
3. you use comparison between double and int `(*a!=NULL)` which might be wrong because there might not be exact representation of 0 in double

You need to decide upon the correct method.
I would suggest passing the number of elements to the method or use STL (vector).

Comment: 2 is wrong; `NULL` is guaranteed to evaluate to an integral `0`, which has an exact representation in `double`. Mind you, it still makes no sense (because `NULL` is meant to be used with pointers, and because `0.` is normally a perfectly normal value for `double`), but not for the reason you said.

Comment: you are right about pointers but he is evaluating the actual double value ==> *a!=NULL

Comment: That's why I said it makes no sense, but it's wrong to say that it's incorrect since 0 has no exact representation in `double`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;
double calculateAverage(double *a);

int main(){

double *dArray;
int n, m;

cout<<"\nplease enter the size of the array: ";
cin>>n;
dArray = new double[n];

for(m=0; m<n; m++){
    cout<<"\nplease enter the number: ";
    cin>>dArray[m];
}
//*(dArray+m+1) = NULL; // i add this, so for the address after m+1 to be NULL
*(dArray+m+1)=numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN( );// Jack gave the idea.

cout<<"\n the average of the array is : "<<calculateAverage(dArray)<<endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
}


double calculateAverage(double *a){
    double total = 0;
    int iCounter = 0;
\\while(*a!=NULL){   // here is the problem!! why it can't be NULL or 0 or empty? // edit from a to *a
    while(!_isnan(*a)){ //Jack's idea.
        total = total+*a;
        a++;
        iCounter++;
    }

    return total/(iCounter-1); //here edit, from iCounter to iCounter-1
}
```

i try to modify the code according to @Jack's comments. others were giving very valuable ideas as well. Thank you all very much.

i think the code is considered to be workable now.